# Kernel hashtable crash while iterating

Tags: c, linux, hashtable

I am writing two basic syscalls. One adds nodes containing a userspace string to the hash table, and the other dumps the contents of the table.

After adding a few items and calling the dump function, it prints one item then crashes with `BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at`

I tried to remove all code related to the userspace string to make sure the error wasn't coming from that. I adding a `table_node` with only `next` and `key` but I ran into the same error.

I have a feeling that I am overlooking something very simple. Does anything jump out with how I am adding or walking the table?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/hashtable.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

DEFINE_HASHTABLE(table, 10);

struct table_node {

    unsigned long key;
    struct hlist_node next;
    char * name;
};

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(add_to_table, const char *, name) {

    struct table_node newNode;
    long strLen;
    long copied;
    int maxLen = 100;

    // Get length of userspace string
    strLen = strnlen_user(name, maxLen); 
    if (strLen <=0 || strLen > maxLen){
       return -EINVAL;
    }

    char s[strLen];
    newNode.name = s;

   // Copy string to kernel space
   copied = strncpy_from_user(newNode.name, name, strLen); 
   if (copied <= 0 || copied > maxLen){
       return -EINVAL;
   }

    newNode.key = (hash(name) % HASH_SIZE(table));

    hash_add(table, &newNode.next, newNode.key);

    return 0;
}

SYSCALL_DEFINE0(dump_table) {

    int bkt = 0;
    table_node * ptr = NULL;

    // Print each entry in the hash table
    hash_for_each_(table, bkt, ptr, next){
        printk("\tkey=%lu,bucket %d\n", ptr->key bkt);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `struct table_node newNode;` and `char s[strLen];
    newNode.name = s;` all of these are local variables, they don't exists after the function returns. Don't you need to allocate them dynamically? Also, don't you have a bug - when `strnlen_user(name` returns `maxLen` then the `newNode.name` will be not null terminated (does `strncpy_from_user` always null terminates the string?)?

Answer (score 0):

Kamil's solution worked.

I forgot to dynamically allocate memory. Adding these two lines resolved my issue.

```
table_node *newNode = kmalloc(sizeof(table_node), GFP_KERNEL);

newNode-fname = kmalloc(strLen * sizeof(char)+1, GFP_KERNEL);
```